# Creating a new variable when running nested regression models

Tags: r, purrr

I am running a series of regressions using nesting and mapping in purrr. I have two dataframes: `df` is the data I am running regressions on, and `regression_models` is the list of regressions to run.

```
library(tidyr)

set.seed(1)
df <- data.frame(x1 = rnorm(100, 0, 1),
                 x2 = rnorm(100, 0, 1),
                 y = sample(0:1, 100, replace = TRUE), 
                 group = sample(c("control", "treatment1", "treatment2", "treatment3"), 100, replace = TRUE),
                 var = 1) |> 
  pivot_wider(names_from = "group", values_from = "var")

regression_models <- data.frame(outcome = c("y", "y", "y", "y", "y", "y"),
                                arm1 = c("treatment1", "treatment2", "treatment3", "treatment1", "treatment1", "treatment2"),
                                arm2 = c("control", "control", "control", "treatment2", "treatment3", "treatment3"),
                                covariates = c("x1 + x2", "x1 + x2", "x1 + x2", "x1 + x2", "x1 + x2", "x1 + x2"))
```

I would like to define a variable `treatment_var` from existing columns of `df`, based on the contents of `regression_models$arm1` and `regression_models$arm2`, and then to use that `treatment_var` when running the regressions in the corresponding row of `regression_models`.

Specifically, when I run the regression in the first row of `regression_models`, I would like `treatment_var` to be defined as follows:

```
library(dplyr)

treatment_var <- case_when(df$treatment1 == 1 ~ TRUE,
                           df$control == 1 ~ FALSE)
```

and when running the regression in the second row of `regression_models`, I would like the definition of `treatment_var` to be:

```
treatment_var <- case_when(df$treatment2 == 1 ~ TRUE,
                           df$control == 1 ~ FALSE)
```

and so on.

Below is the code I am currently using to run the regressions - but here `treatment_var` is assumed to exist in `df` and does not change based on the contents of `regression_models`. Is there a way to achieve this?

```
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)
library(broom)

regression_output <- regression_models |> 
  mutate(formula = paste0(outcome, "~ treatment_var + ", covariates),
         fit = map(formula, ~ tidy(glm(.x, family = binomial, df)))) |> 
  unnest(fit)
```

Comment: At least from the example you've given, it seems as though your plan is to run a bunch of different regressions contrasting particular pairs of treatments. From a statistical point of view, I think it would be better (statistically and computationally more efficient and coherent) to fit a single model including all treatments, then to use a tool like `emmeans` to compute contrasts/pairwise comparisons between particular combinations of treatments ...

Comment: Thanks for your advice, Ben. I haven't seen an approach like that used before, but I'll look into it for next time I'm doing something like this. But for now I'm tied to following an existing statistical analysis plan.